# Materialize Slider Not Working shows grey screen even if it's initialized

Tags: javascript, slider, materialize

As the title says, I access the materialize css and js locally, downloaded from there site and it occurs like this if i cleared my cache and cookies then im getting this error from the materialize.min.js as shown in the
[picture here (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8F4R.png)

here is my html and js code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});

  $('#btnLogin').click(function(){
    postOrderID();
  });
  $('#loginPanel').click(function(){
   $('#modalLogin').openModal();
  })
        

function postOrderID() {
 var _pass = document.getElementById("txtPayment").value;
 var dataString = 'tablepass=' + _pass; //+ '&name=' + _name + '&pax=' + _pax + '&pass=' + _pass;
 if (_pass == '') {
  alert("Textbox null");
 } else {
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/getinsertOR.php",
  data: dataString,
  }).done(function(data){
   console.log(data);
       if (data == 'Success') {
             window.location.replace("index.html");
       }else if (data == 'Failed'){
        alert("Wrong Password")
       }else if (data == 'Damage'){
    alert("Table Damaged")
       }else{
           window.location.replace("index.html");
       }
   }).fail(function(){
    
  })
 }
  return false;
}

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="slider fullscreen">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="images/a3.jpg"><!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
          <a id="loginPanel" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger">Login</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/a2.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption left-align">
          <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/a1.jpg"><!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption right-align">
          <h3 class="light black-text text-lighten-1">Right Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light black-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

    <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modalLogin" class="modal container">
    <div class="modal-content" style="text-align: center; padding-left: 20% ; padding-right: 20%">
      <label>Note: Confirmation Key is located at the table</label>
      <input id="txtPayment" type="text" id="tablepass" name="tablepass" placeholder="Enter Confirmation Key" style="text-align: center"> <br>
      <a id="btnLogin" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger">Submit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>              
<script src="js/loginController.js"></script>      
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you solve this? im getting same problem here.

Comment: Hmm solved by `$(document).ready(function () { $('.slider').slider({full_width: true, height:1000}); });` simply 'start' seems not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Bro it works completely fine in my PC. Just check if you have **disabled** javascript in mozilla firefox or use another browser to run the page. It will definitely work.

To enable JavaScript for Mozilla Firefox: Click the Tools drop-down menu and select Options. Check the boxes next to Block pop-up windows, Load images automatically, and Enable JavaScript. Refresh your browser by right-clicking anywhere on the page and selecting Reload, or by using the Reload button in the toolbar.